# Can't execute js script, returned value appears on screen and stops script

Tags: javascript

I made script for myself to use in browser game - tribal wars.

```
document.getElementById("mp_att").click();
setTimeout(
    function(){
        TroopTemplates.useTemplate(1889);
        document.getElementById("target_attack").click();
    },700 
); 
setTimeout(
    function(){
        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_go").click();
    },1000 
);
```

Everything works fine, when I type it into console (Ctrl+Shift+K) and it returns some kind of value like 476, but I wanted to use this script very often. But when I bookmark this script with a `javascript:` prefix, it stops working. Returned value appears on screen and stops the script. How to solve this problem?

To be more exact:

`document.getElementById("mp_att").click();`
select "attack" on selected village.

Then window is shown, and I have to select troops.

`TroopTemplates.useTemplate(1889);` selects them.

This function, executed alone returns only "false"

`document.getElementById("target_attack").click();`

Code above chooses, that I want to attack this village.

Then one more popup is shown. (In case to confirm sending troops)

`document.getElementById("troop_confirm_go").click();`

This code confirms, and sends troops.

How can I ignore/hide returned values? Or maybe there is another way to quickly execute script?

Comment: Could you elaborate in your question a bit? What exactly is happening when you run the script and what are you intending to happen? Screenshots of the console and browser would also be very helpful.

Comment: This code doesn't return anything. You are explaining another piece of code, for sure.

Comment: This code sends troops to previously selected village. 

After using this script, console returns only value, for example - 144 (And everything works fine)
But when I use this script as a link, returned walue appears on blank page. I am not longer on page, where I still should be.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand anything. You must to share the Minimal, complete and verifiable example, reproducing the issue you have. With the code you share it's impossible to help you. You must read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to, see if you are able to understand more now.

Answer (score 1):

ok.. let me know if I at least understood what you're trying to achieve:

You're injecting your scripts into another site using the browsers dev-tools.
Instead of copy/pasting and running the scripts in the developer tools you want to add the script as a javascript source-reference to your browsers bookmarks to call them again and again.

I didn’t try but I’m pretty sure this is not going to work.
I’m curious it seems to partially work for you- maybe someone comes up with a working solution.

But: you can

- Write a Browser Plugin to inject the code
- Use browser automation = embed the browser as control in another app and inject the scripts this way

Comment: I always tried this in firefox. Didn't work. But I tried once in Chrome and it worked without any problems. I don't know why, but it keeps working, and I am happy about it.